# Magento RWD theme - layered navigation not showing

Tags: magento, responsive-design, magento-1.9

We like the layered navigation on the right side of the category page.
Therefore, I inserted following code in our local.xml file:

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
 <reference name="root">
     <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
 </reference>
```

In my catalog.xml file, I edit this line:

```
<reference name="left_first">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
            ...
```

to

```
<reference name="right">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
            ...
```

On large viewports, I see the layered navigation on the right side, as it should be.
As soon as I resize the window to a tablet resolution, the layered navigation disappears. Normally, the layered navigation is added on top of all products in the tablet resolution with the label "FILTER".

Comment: you've answered your own question really - the css in the rwd template is expectting to alter the left column on smaller viewports, but you have moved the content to a right column.  Add css based with @media screen for the correct size and do what you need with the right column - width 100% for example.    You may be better off putting the layered back to where it was and floating the left column right instead.